# Value is changing when clicking on another input

Tags: javascript, php, html

`onkeyup` on the input and putting in a new value the total should be updated with the price but its changing for example if i put the value of `2` in the first input the total changes to 50 which is correct but if i type a value in the second input the value goes back to 42

I forgot this issue is related specifically from input from a database please visit the site http://naturalflame.altervista.org/ login guest@naturalflame.com pass guest

the error is on the review and customize page

```js
function UpdatePrice(id,price){
            var amount = document.getElementById("amount" + id).value;
            var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
            var totalText = document.getElementById("totalText");
            
            total -= price;
            total += price * amount;
            console.log(total);
            
            totalText.innerHTML = "TOTAL: $" + total;
        }
```

```html
<table> 
         <tr> 
             <th>Order Details</th>  
             <th>Price</th> 
                <th>Quantity</th> 
         </tr>
            <?
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE email='$email'";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
                $priceTotal = 0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                 $id = $row->id;
                 $detail = $row->details;
                    $price = $row->price;
                    
                    $priceTotal = $priceTotal + $price;
                    
                    $details = explode("|",$detail);
                    
                    $size = $details[0] . "ml";
                    $flavor = $details[1];
                    $blend = $details[2];
                    echo "
                     <tr>
                      <td>$size,$flavor,$blend</td>
                            <td>$$price</td>
                            <input type='number' class='hidden' id='price$id' value='$price'>
                            <td><input type='number' id='amount$id' value='1' onclick='UpdatePrice($id,$price)'></td>
                        </tr>
                    ";
                }
                echo "
                 <input type='number' class='hidden' id='total' value='$priceTotal'>
                 <span id='totalText'>TOTAL: $$priceTotal</span>
                    <button class='btn btn-info' onclick='Checkout()'>Checkout</button>
                ";
   ?>
     </table>
        </div><!--end main-->
```

Comment: I got into your page and couldn't find the error. Can you explain it better please?

Comment: if you select "review and customize" the total value when you click on one of the inputs changes to an incorrect sum of the cost

Comment: Try adding `document.getElementById("total").value = total;` before `totalText.innerHTML = "TOTAL: $" + total;`.